# MySQL: multiple counts with join

Tags: mysql, join, count

Here are my two tables:

```
[items]
- id - model - location_id -

  1    mA      23
  2    mA      23
  3    mA      23
  4    mB      24
  5    mB      24
  6    mC      25
  7    mC      26


[locations]
- id - name -

  23   aisle-3
  24   aisle-4
  25   aisle-5
  26   aisle-6
```

I am trying to query the `locations` table for the location names and also bring back a count of the items at that location. Here is something I tried to no avail:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(item.id)
FROM locations
INNER JOIN items AS item ON (item.location_id = locations.id)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(item.id)
FROM locations l
INNER JOIN items AS i 
ON i.location_id = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

And if you want to get `COUNT()` even when there is no item assigned to that location you should `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.